# Read Multipolygon geoJson data and display on Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, polygons

I would like to read/display geoJson data on a Leaflet map. I have 10 multipolygons stored in the geoJson file and would like to color each in a different color.

Reading the documentation on Leaflet's [website](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/), I used the following code to read and color the polygons:

```
//Adding multipolygons to map
L.geoJSON(dataName, {
    style: function(feature) {
        switch (feature.properties.id) {
            case '100': return {color: "#ff0000"};
            case '200':   return {color: "#0ff000"};
        ...
        case '1000':   return {color: "#0000ff"};
        }
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

And this is the datafile:

```
//Data file
var dataName = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features":[

{ "type":"Feature","id":100,"properties":{"id":"100","count":0},"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"GEODATA"}},
"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[MANY COORDINATES]
}},
{"type":"Feature","id":200,"properties":{"id":"200","count":0},"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"GEODATA"}},
"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[MANY COORDINATES]
}},

...

{"type":"Feature","id":1000,"properties":{"id":"1000","count":0},"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"GEODATA"}},
"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[MANY COORDINATES]
}]}
```

Nothing is displayed. I think the error lies inside the function. Not really sure what "feature" does. Any clues?

Thx!

Comment: Do you have a `default` case in your `switch`?

Comment: Could not reproduce your issue: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/241/ You should consider sharing more code, with some sample data (including coordinates), ideally reproducing your issue on JSFiddle / Plunker / etc.

Comment: Trying to create a Qlikview Map extension. Copy-pasted your code with my coordinates. Everything seems to be running smoothly. However, nothing is displayed on the map. Then tried to add a simple mark on the map. The mark is displayed.

Comment: When I say "reproduce your issue on JSFiddle etc.", I mean share it so that other users can see what is happening. Just saying it works / does not work will not help us understand your issue any deeper.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be using `dataName.features`?

`L.geoJSON(dataName, {`

Should be:

`L.geoJSON(dataName.features, {`

Here is a code snippet from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42700253/how-do-i-change-the-style-of-a-geojson-layer-of-linestrings-in-leaflet-1-0-3/42700818#42700818) I made:

`geojson = L.geoJson(myGeoJson.features, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
    style: styleFeature,
}).addTo(myLeafletMap);`

Comment: Tried adding .features but nothing happened :/

Comment: Have you got it showing on the map with its default colours? Can you hit a breakpoint in the switch statement and see that you have your data in the function?

Comment: No, will try. Trying to create a Qlikview Map extension.